# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH with GeckoDriver Selenium Firefox

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

I don't know Pycharm - or Python well enough to troubleshoot just what went wrong. It seems top me as if this simply bit of code should execute but I get a jumble of text that says nothing to me.

Anyone else using Selenium get this error and know how to fix it?
The physical code -

```
"C:\Users\Noah Linton\PycharmProjects\EdgenuityBot\venv\Scripts\python.exe" 
"C:/Users/Noah Linton/PycharmProjects/EdgenuityBot/Edgenuity Bot"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Noah Linton\PycharmProjects\EdgenuityBot\venv\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python36_64\Lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/Noah Linton/PycharmProjects/EdgenuityBot/Edgenuity Bot", line                         
3, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
File "C:\Users\Noah Linton\PycharmProjects\EdgenuityBot\venv\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 148, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\Noah Linton\PycharmProjects\EdgenuityBot\venv\lib\site-
packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' 
executable needs to be in PATH. 


Process finished with exit code 1
```

The executive code

```
 from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://auth.edgenuity.com/Login/Login/Student")
button = driver.find_element_by_id('LoginSubmit')
button.click()
```

Comment: and the error is...? Please provide exact error plus relevant code.

Comment: Sorry! I added the screenshot in

Comment: Trace back is python’s way of returning the error/exception. Posting what it said here, and a relevant snippet of code, could yield your answer.

Comment: I updated it to display the relevant code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says it all :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Which implies that *GeckoDriver* binary is not in the *Classpath*

While working with *Selenium v3.x* you have to download the latest *GeckoDriver* from this [*url*](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and store it in your system and mention the absolute path while initiating the *webdriver* and *Web Browser* session as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://auth.edgenuity.com/Login/Login/Student")
button = driver.find_element_by_id('LoginSubmit')
button.click()
```

Comment: That worked! I would like to add however that there should be an r before
r"C:\\path\\to\\geckodriver.exe as to convert the path string into a raw string instead of a normal string for anyone else asking a question like this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

For what little help it might be, the critical parts of the traceback are

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

line 3, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' 
executable needs to be in PATH.
```

It seems that the Firefox webdriver isn't in the defined search path that your main program sees.  There's something called `geckodriver` that isn't available.

Check your installation and configuration for this package.  Consult with your class instructors and classmates for help.  I suspect that the repair is something with your local set-up, beyond our knowledge here.