# TOR Selenium Python with binary path given THROWS ERROR geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, macos, selenium, geckodriver, tor

I was looking at [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29905649/13112739) and copied the code for MacOS (top of answer, also reproduced below for convenience).

```
import os    # Code from answer linked above
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium import webdriver


# path to the firefox binary inside the Tor package
binary = '/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'
if os.path.exists(binary) is False:
    raise ValueError("The binary path to Tor firefox does not exist.")
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary(binary)


browser = None
def get_browser(binary=None):
    global browser  
    # only one instance of a browser opens, remove global for multiple instances
    if not browser: 
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
    return browser

if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = get_browser(binary=firefox_binary)
    urls = (
        ('tor browser check', 'https://check.torproject.org/'),
        ('ip checker', 'http://icanhazip.com')
    )
    for url_name, url in urls:
        print "getting", url_name, "at", url
        browser.get(url)
```

I keep getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "torselenium.py", line 22, in <module>
    browser = get_browser(binary=firefox_binary)
  File "torselenium.py", line 18, in get_browser
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/Users/user/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

This error is very similar to the error described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051), where the recomendation is to set a `firefox_binary` path. Yet I have already done this and verified (verification proof below) that there is a firefox binary at that path.

```
$ ls /Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox
```

In fact, if I set the binary path (line 7) to `'~/Applications/TorBrowser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'`, it gives me the `ValueError`, so there is definitely a binary there.

I also [checked if I have execute permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50512526/13826888), which I do and I tried changing `browser` from a global to local variable, to no help.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: `firefox` and `geckodriver` are two different executables. What does `command -v geckodriver` return? If not installed, `brew install geckodriver`

Comment: @hoefling `brew install geckodriver` solved my problem. Not sure why, as I have used selenium in the past and I don't think I had it installed using brew - just downloaded the executable from Mozilla

Comment: You can install it however you want, downloading the executable from [geckodriver releases](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) is also fine, just make sure the file is in PATH.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_profile import FirefoxProfile 
    
driver = webdriver.Firefox(
                executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install(),
                firefox_profile= FirefoxProfile(R"C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\TorBrowser\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default"),
                firefox_binary=FirefoxBinary(R'C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\TorBrowser\Browser\firefox.exe')
            )
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

i have to use binary, profile an GeckoDriverManager library

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close enough. Using [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) to initiate a *Mozilla Firefox* browsing context through [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) driven [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660195/why-firefox-requires-geckodriver/43661697#43661697) you have to download the latest [GeckoDriver v0.26.0](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0) and store it in your system and mention the *absolute path* while initiating the *Web Browser* session as follows :

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary, executable_path='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
```

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to connect to Tor browser using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53942553/how-to-connect-to-tor-browser-using-python/53942783#53942783)

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions on **WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH** error in:

- [WebDriverException: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH even though it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49947694/webdriverexception-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path-even-though-it/49955135#49955135)
- [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH with GeckoDriver Selenium Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48551161/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-geckodriver-executable/48567553#48567553)
- [Python 3.5 - “Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44631020/python-3-5-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path/44632206#44632206)